# How do I fix this class issue?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I've been getting 2 errors for this code:

> 'totalCost' is not a type

> 'cout' was not declared in this scope

What am I missing?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class License{
public:
    int vat, totalCost;
    int calculateVat();
    };



class PurchasedLicense :public License{
    calculateVat(totalCost){ //the first error seems to be here
    vat = totalCost/10;
    return vat;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Type your license cost: "; //second is here
    cin >> calculateVat;
    cout << "Your VAT is: ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error can be fixed by adding type names for the return type and argument of `calculateVat()`.

The second error can be fixed by adding `std::` before `cout` (and `cin`).

Also, there is another error that the `calculateVat` variable used in the `main()` function is not declared. Declare that variable to fix this error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class License{
public:
    int vat, totalCost;
    int calculateVat();
    };



class PurchasedLicense :public License{
    // add types
    int calculateVat(int totalCost){ //the first error seems to be here
    vat = totalCost/10;
    return vat;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // declare the variable used
    int calculateVat;
    // add std::
    std::cout << "Type your license cost: "; //second is here
    std::cin >> calculateVat;
    std::cout << "Your VAT is: ";
}
```

Comment: I thought maybe `calculateVat` was supposed to be a (pure) virtual function in `License` which is defined in `PurchasedLicense`?

Comment: @MikeCAT your example is not calling `PurchasedLicense::calculateVat()`, which is also not overriding `License::calculateVat()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [MikeCAT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67419387/65863), which explains why you are getting the errors you mention, and how to fix them.  However, there are other problems with your code.

`calculateVat()` needs to be marked as `virtual` in `License` in order for `PurchasedLicense` to override it.  And you need an object instance of `PurchasedLicense` for `main()` to call `calculateVat()` on.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class License{
public:
    int vat, totalCost;
    virtual int calculateVat() = 0;
};

class PurchasedLicense : public License{
public:
    int calculateVat() override {
        vat = totalCost/10;
        return vat;
    }
};

int main()
{
    PurchasedLicense lic;
    std::cout << "Type your license cost: ";
    std::cin >> lic.totalCost;
    std::cout << "Your VAT is: " << lic.calculateVat();
}
```